# Copy constructor for derived class from base pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, copy-constructor, derived-class

I have looked all around and can't find the answer to my question anywhere. I am trying to use a copy constructor of a derived class from a pointer array of base classes. The only thing I have learned is I should probably use dynamic_cast but cant get that working.

This is the important parts of my code so far (original is way to big since I have 16 different files but this should be enough).

EDIT: The error I receive doing it this way is |26|error: cannot dynamic_cast '& properties[0]' (of type 'class Property**') to type 'class Commercial*' (source is not a pointer to class)|

```
#include "rentals.h"
#include "commercial.h"
#include "sales.h"
#include "comSales.h"
#include "resSales.h"
#include "resRentals.h"
#include "comRentals.h"

const int MAX_PROPERTIES = 5;

int main(void) {
   int i;


   Property *properties[MAX_PROPERTIES];


   properties[0] = new Commercial("Notting Hill McDonalds", "4 Gardiner Road",
                                  "Notting Hill", 5000, "Li3000");


   properties[1] = new ResRentals("Janet Dalgleish", "30 Firhill Court",
                           "Mary Hill", 4000, 500.00, 300.00, 4);


   properties[2] = new Commercial(dynamic_cast<Commercial*>(properties[0]));  // <-- the copy constructor I can not get to work.


   delete[] properties;

   return 0;
}
```

commercial.cpp file

```
#include "property_a.h"
#include "commercial.h"


Commercial::Commercial() : Property() {
   owner = "NULL";
   address = "NULL";
   suburb = "NULL";
   postcode = 0;
   license = "NULL";
}

Commercial::Commercial(string theOwner, string theAddress,
                        string theSuburb, int thepostCode,
                        string theLicense): Property(theOwner, theAddress,
                        theSuburb, thepostCode), license(theLicense) {}

Commercial::~Commercial() {}

Commercial::Commercial(const Commercial& orig) : Property(orig),
                        license(orig.getLicense()) {}

void Commercial::print() {
   cout << getOwner() << endl;
   cout << getAddress() << endl;
   cout << getSuburb() << endl;
   cout << getPostcode() << endl;
   cout << getLicense() << endl;
}
```

commercial.h file

```
#ifndef __COMMERCIAL_H__
#define __COMMERCIAL_H__


#include "property_a.h"

class Commercial :  public virtual Property
{
protected:
  string license;

public:
  Commercial();
  Commercial(string theOwner, string theAddress, string theSuburb,
              int thepostCode, string theLicense);

   ~Commercial() ;

   Commercial(const Commercial& orig);

  void input() ;   // Data input for a Shop object
  void print() ;  // Data output for a Shop object

  string getLicense() const {return license;};   //Note the use of const

  void setLicense(string theLicense) {license = theLicense;};

};
```

property_a.cpp file

```
#include "property_a.h"

Property::Property(){
   owner = "NULL";
   address = "NULL";
   suburb = "NULL";
   postcode = 0;
}

Property::Property(string theOwner, string theAddress,
                   string theSuburb, int thepostCode):
                     owner(theOwner), address(theAddress),
                     suburb(theSuburb), postcode(thepostCode){}

Property::~Property() {}

Property::Property(const Property& orig) :
                     owner(orig.getOwner()), address(orig.getAddress()),
                     suburb(orig.getSuburb()), postcode(getPostcode()) {}
```

property_a.h file

```
#ifndef __PROPERTY_A_H__
#define __PROPERTY_A_H__


/*TODO  REQUIRED HEADER FILES AND NAMESPACES*/
#include <string>
#include "utility1.h"

class Property
{
protected:
  string owner;
  string address;
  string suburb;
  int postcode;

public:
  Property();
  Property(string theOwner, string theAddress, string theSuburb, int thepostCode);
  virtual ~Property();
  Property(const Property& orig);
  virtual void input() ;   // Data input for a Property object
  virtual void print() ;  // Data output for a Property object

  string getOwner() const {return owner;};   //Note the use of const
  string getAddress() const {return address;};
  string getSuburb() const {return suburb;};
  int getPostcode() const {return postcode;};

  void setOwner(string newOwner) {owner = newOwner;};
  void setAddress(string newAddress) {address = newAddress;};
  void setSuburb( string  newSuburb) {suburb = newSuburb;};
  void setPostcode(int  newPostcode) {postcode = newPostcode;};
};
#endif
```

I hope this is enough details

Comment: Your `Property` class does not need a user-defined copy constructor.  All the members are int's and std::strings -- they are perfectly copyable using the compiler-supplied copy constructor.  Same thing with the `Commercial` class -- no need for a user-defined copy constructor.

Comment: for some reason I do whenever using array of pointers, using code::blocks with -Wall -pedantic -ansi flags

Comment: Believe me, there is no need for these functions in your classes.  Second, pointers are not objects.  You use copy operations when you're copying objects, not pointers.

Comment: well I read when learning that if you use array of pointers to base objects you should ALWAYS define your own copy constructor so I did

Comment: You are not calling the copy constructor in the code that has the error.  Please look at the answer that @James Adkison gave.  Once you fix the error and actually call the copy constructor, you will (magically) see that you never needed to write one yourself -- the compiler's version would be called.

Comment: `well I read when learning that if you use array of pointers to base objects you should ALWAYS define your own copy constructor so I did`  Nonsense, or you didn't understand completely what was being stated.  The classes as you have written them, do *not* need any user-defined copy constructor.  Plain and simple.  If within the class itself, a resource (such as a pointer to dynamically allocated memory) was being used, *then* a user-defined copy constructor for that class would be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to see the errors but it looks like you aren't calling the copy constructor at all:

```
new Commercial(dynamic_cast<Commercial*>(properties[0]));
```

is like calling

```
Commercial(Commercial * other);
```

so you need

```
new Commercial(*dynamic_cast<Commercial*>(properties[0]));
```

Comment: Sorry, editing to show the error. adding a '*' in that location is not changing the error at all

Comment: EDIT: I just realised when messing around i had 
new Commercial(*dynamic_cast<Commercial*>(&properties[0]));
after removing '&' it is working! thanks a bunch, new it had to be something small I just couldn't figure it out at all.

Answer (score 2):

> properties[2] = new Commercial(dynamic_cast(properties[0]));  // <-- the copy constructor I can not get to work.

This is casting `properties[0]` to `Commercial*`. But this isn't the signature of your copy constructor. Therefore, you need `new Commercial(*dynamic_cast<Commercial*>(properties[0]));`.

In this example you could use `static_cast<Commercial&>(*properties[0])` since you ***know*** `properties[0]` is a `Commercial` type.

**However**, in general if you're using `dynamic_cast` it probably means you're not sure what the derived type is and you would need to check for `NULL` (i.e., the cast failed) before dereferencing.

### Alternative

You could consider a polymorphic API to take care of this for you.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    Base* clone() const = 0;
};

class D1 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~D1() override = default;
    D1* clone() const { return new D1(*this); }
};

class D2 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~D2() override = default;
    D2* clone() const { return new D2(*this); }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> b1(new D2());
    std::unique_ptr<Base> b2(b1->clone());

    return 0;
}
```